# (Layout Plus 9.2) How to copy a part from one MAX file to another

Tags: layout, orcad

I have a Layout Plus 9.2 file.
I want to copy some components on it to another file (I don't have component library).
How can I export those components to a new library?
How can I copy them to a new Layout Plus file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the old OrCAD 9.2 and 10.5, you can open the layout file (*.max) with the Library Manager as if it were a library.  Here are the steps:

1. Start OrCAD.
2. select the menu `Tools -> Library Manager`
3. In the Library Manager under the list of libraries click `Add...` as if you were adding a library.
4. In the Open File dialog at the bottom, select `Files of type` `Board (*.max)`
5. Choose the file from which you want to extract the libraries.  Click `Open`
6. Now your layout file should appear in the list of libraries.  You can save the footprints in a separate library and use them like any other footprints.

This approach was [originally published here (link goes to OrCADexchange Yahoo group)](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/OrCADexchange/conversations/topics/1123).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any way to copy multiple components at one time?

Comment: I'm afraid that library components have to copied one at a time.  OrCAD 9.2 layout overall is not the most intuitive and friendly layout package (as you have probably noticed).